# Data recovery from an Android struck in bootloop

Tags: android, data-recovery

How do I recover data from Android phone which is struck in bootloop? It boots into recovery mode and fastboot mode without any problem. Its Not rooted. 'Developer Options' were enabled. 'USB Debugging' wasn't enabled. It is detected by PC when in switched off condition but can't be detected in Recovery or fastboot mode. Model Asus 5z.

Comment: You would have more luck in XDA developer fourms.